# How to sort ArrayAdapter<String> in Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-arrayadapter

I am tryign to populate an `ExpandableList` items in android. Currently, I am getting the values of the headers from a string-array from the `resources` as follow:

```
String[] processesValues = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.processes);
```

Then I sort the `Array` using the following:

```
Arrays.sort(processesValues);
```

Afterward, I am loading the `Arra`y in the `ArrayAdaptor` list as follow:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> processesAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            R.layout.places_list_item, R.id.placeNameTv, processesValues);
```

Now, the headers `Array` is sorted alphabetically, but the `ArrayAdaptor` list are not sorted. for example, if I have the following `string-array` in resouces:

```
<string-array name="processes">
    <item>cab</item>
    <item>abc</item>
    <item>bac</item>
</string-array>
```

I get and sort the `Array` like this:

```
> abc
> bac
> cab
```

then i try to put it in the `ArrayAdapter`, but the `ArrayAdaptor` show the following headers when running the app:

```
> cab
> abc
> bac
```

what am I doing wrong ?

**UPDATE**

here is my full code:

```
public class ExpandableListDataPump {

private static Context context;

public ExpandableListDataPump(Context current) {
    this.context = current;
}

public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getData() {

    String[] placesValues;

    Comparator<String> ALPHABETICAL_ORDER1 = new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String object1, String object2) {
            int res = String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(object1.toString(), object2.toString());
            return res;
        }
    };


    placesValues = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.places);
    ArrayAdapter<String> locationsAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            R.layout.places_list_item, R.id.placeNameTv, placesValues);
    List<String> locationsList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < locationsAdaptor.getCount(); i++) {
        locationsList1.add((String) locationsAdaptor.getItem(i));
        Collections.sort(locationsList1, ALPHABETICAL_ORDER1);
    }

    // -----------

    placesValues = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.places2);
    ArrayAdapter<String> locationsAdaptor2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            R.layout.places_list_item, R.id.placeNameTv, placesValues);
    List<String> locationsList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < locationsAdaptor2.getCount(); i++) {
        locationsList2.add((String) locationsAdaptor2.getItem(i));
        Collections.sort(locationsList2, ALPHABETICAL_ORDER1);
    }

    // -----------

    placesValues = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.places3);
    ArrayAdapter<String> locationsAdaptor3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            R.layout.places_list_item, R.id.placeNameTv, placesValues);
    List<String> locationsList3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < locationsAdaptor3.getCount(); i++) {
        locationsList3.add((String) locationsAdaptor3.getItem(i));
        Collections.sort(locationsList3, ALPHABETICAL_ORDER1);
    }

    // -----------

    placesValues = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.places4);
    ArrayAdapter<String> locationsAdaptor4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            R.layout.places_list_item, R.id.placeNameTv, placesValues);
    List<String> locationsList4 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < locationsAdaptor4.getCount(); i++) {
        locationsList4.add((String) locationsAdaptor4.getItem(i));
        Collections.sort(locationsList4, ALPHABETICAL_ORDER1);
    }

    // -----------

    placesValues = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.places5);
    ArrayAdapter<String> locationsAdaptor5 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            R.layout.places_list_item, R.id.placeNameTv, placesValues);
    List<String> locationsList5 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < locationsAdaptor2.getCount(); i++) {
        locationsList5.add((String) locationsAdaptor5.getItem(i));
        Collections.sort(locationsList5, ALPHABETICAL_ORDER1);
    }

    // -----------

    placesValues = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.places6);
    ArrayAdapter<String> locationsAdaptor6 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            R.layout.places_list_item, R.id.placeNameTv, placesValues);
    List<String> locationsList6 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < locationsAdaptor2.getCount(); i++) {
        locationsList6.add((String) locationsAdaptor6.getItem(i));
        Collections.sort(locationsList6, ALPHABETICAL_ORDER1);
    }

    // -----------

    placesValues = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.places7);
    ArrayAdapter<String> locationsAdaptor7 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            R.layout.places_list_item, R.id.placeNameTv, placesValues);
    List<String> locationsList7 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < locationsAdaptor7.getCount(); i++) {
        locationsList7.add((String) locationsAdaptor7.getItem(i));
        Collections.sort(locationsList7, ALPHABETICAL_ORDER1);
    }

    // -----------

    placesValues = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.places8);
    ArrayAdapter<String> locationsAdaptor8 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            R.layout.places_list_item, R.id.placeNameTv, placesValues);
    List<String> locationsList8 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < locationsAdaptor8.getCount(); i++) {
        locationsList8.add((String) locationsAdaptor8.getItem(i));
        Collections.sort(locationsList8, ALPHABETICAL_ORDER1);
    }

    // -----------

    placesValues = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.places9);
    ArrayAdapter<String> locationsAdaptor9 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            R.layout.places_list_item, R.id.placeNameTv, placesValues);
    List<String> locationsList9 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < locationsAdaptor9.getCount(); i++) {
        locationsList9.add((String) locationsAdaptor9.getItem(i));
        Collections.sort(locationsList9, ALPHABETICAL_ORDER1);
    }

    // -----------

    placesValues = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.places10);
    ArrayAdapter<String> locationsAdaptor10 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            R.layout.places_list_item, R.id.placeNameTv, placesValues);
    List<String> locationsList10 = new ArrayList<String>();
    String placesValuesString10 = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < locationsAdaptor10.getCount(); i++) {
        locationsList10.add((String) locationsAdaptor10.getItem(i));
        Collections.sort(locationsList10, ALPHABETICAL_ORDER1);
    }

    // -----------

    List<List<String>> allLocationLists = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    allLocationLists.add(locationsList1);
    allLocationLists.add(locationsList2);
    allLocationLists.add(locationsList3);
    allLocationLists.add(locationsList4);
    allLocationLists.add(locationsList5);
    allLocationLists.add(locationsList6);
    allLocationLists.add(locationsList7);
    allLocationLists.add(locationsList8);
    allLocationLists.add(locationsList9);
    allLocationLists.add(locationsList10);

    // ----------------

    HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    String[] processesValues = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.processes);
    Arrays.sort(processesValues);

    ArrayAdapter<String> processesAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            R.layout.places_list_item, R.id.placeNameTv, processesValues);

    processesAdaptor.setNotifyOnChange(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < processesAdaptor.getCount(); i++) {
        String test = processesAdaptor.getItem(i).toString();
        System.out.println(test);
        expandableListDetail.put(processesAdaptor.getItem(i), allLocationLists.get(i));
    }

    return expandableListDetail;
}
```

}

Comment: *Now, the headers Array is sorted alphabetically, but the ArrayAdaptor list are not sorted. what am I doing wrong*. Can you elaborate what you mean by this?

Comment: please check the update, thanks  ... @CKing

Comment: Are you sure you're not overwriting the sorted array somewhere? Is there any code in between these two parts..?

Comment: @Vucko : I just recheck again, no overwriting at all. I actually resorted the code so no overwriting happens at all. (i.e.: no code bewteen the two parts )

Comment: @Luksprog : what I understood from you is that, firstly the `Array` that I am passing to the `ArrayAdapter` is shufled again randomly and go back to it is original order, so pre-sorting the Array has no affect what so ever, right ?!

Comment: @Luksprog : would you please guide me to an example on how to add value one by one, thanks

Comment: @Suda.nese I've misread your question. Make sure, like Vucko mentioned, that you're not touching the array somewhere else.

Comment: @Luksprog : here is the full code, please help

Answer (score 2):

Per the Android documentation, "setNotifyOnChange" will only trigger if you use the Adapter's functions to edit the list.  You may need to call [youradapter].notifyDataSetChanged() after sorting.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter#setNotifyOnChange(boolean)